# Ошибка при присвоении даты в Calendar

Tags: дата, android

Здравствуйте, тут такая проблема. Код:

```
String[] arr
Calendar dataOfAnniversary
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

//Далее код программы в котором arr[3] присваивается дате, например "01-01-2000"
.
.
.

dateOfAnniversary = null;
try {
    Log.d(TAG, "1 - " + arr[3]);
    dateOfAnniversary.setTime(sdf.parse(arr[3]));
    Log.d(TAG, "2");
    dateOfAnniversary.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e);
}
```

Логи:

```
1 - 01-00-2000
Exeption: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Соответственно вопрос: Почему я не могу присвоить дату.

**P.S** Я знаю, что `java.lang.NullPointerException` говорит о том, что я присваиваю `null`, но если `arr[3] = null`, тогда почему лог вывел дату, а не `null`?

Comment: 1. Покажите стектрейс исключения.
 2. Покажите больше релевантного кода, в частности, объявление и инициализацию `dateOfAnniversary`.

Comment: @fori1ton Да

Comment: @fori1ton Спасибо

Comment: Есть же режим отладки, в котором можно посмотреть значение каждой переменной! Так поставьте точну остановки (BreakPoint) на строку, в которой у вас NullPointer, и посмотрите значение каждой переменной, зачем для этого создавать вопрос??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего `dateOfAnniversary = null`, отсюда `NullPointerException`.